# Getting average of the past 3 month, but only if that month exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database with a table containing sales. I need to create a report that will show me products and their average selling price for the past 3 months, which would look something like that:

```
SELECT product_code, product_description, ROUND((SUM(sales_value)/3),0) as avg3
FROM sales_data
WHERE sales_period >= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()) - 3, 0)
GROUP BY product_code, product_description;
--sales_period is always 1st of month, ie. 2021-02-01
```

here is the catch: this has to be an average of last 3 months where there was actually a sales.

For example, since we are currently in March:

1. product ABC had no sales in January, so I will have to get values
   from November, December & February.
2. product XYZ, had no sales in November & December, so I need to get
   the data from October, January and February.

Any idea how to crack this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show sample data (as DDL+DML) and expected results (as tabular text *not* images).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the last three months for each product, then use `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT product_code, product_description,
       ROUND((SUM(sales_value) / 3),0) as avg3
FROM (SELECT sd.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER PARTITION BY product_code ORDER BY  YEAR(sales_period) DESC, MONTH(sales_period) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales_data sd
     ) sd
WHERE seqnum <= 3
GROUP BY product_code, product_description;
```

Note:  Some product may not have 3 months of sales.  So I might suggest two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT product_code, product_description,
       AVG(month_sales) as avg3
FROM (SELECT product_code, product_description,
             YEAR(sales_period) as yyyy, MONTH(sales_period) as mm,
             SUM(sales_value) as month_sales,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER PARTITION BY product_code ORDER BY YEAR(sales_period) DESC, MONTH(sales_period) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales_data sd
      GROUP BY product_code, YEAR(sales_period), MONTH(sales_period)
     ) sd
GROUP BY product_code, product_description;
```

Comment: To account for products that may not have 3 months of sales, you could also use the first query and just change this part: sum(sales_value) / count(distinct seqnum). But good answer either way!

Comment: `ORDER BY EOMONTH(...)` (and `GROUP BY`) bit shorter I think it works the same